# Why don't bootstrap codes run on my django website?

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

**Hello**

I'm having trouble applying **bootstrap** to my website in **django**.

I copied the bootstrap link in the html page and wrote the **navbar** codes in the body part, but when I hit runserver, the website page doesn't change at all!

where is the problem from?
I also installed the bootstrap plugin in Visual studio code, but it still doesn't change anything!

**Thank you for your guidance**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF -8">
    <title> {% block title %} {% endblock %} </title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark big-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

    {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share the code

Comment: I have sent the code now

Comment: https://dev.to/thalesbruno/django-bootstrap-basic-setup-5dmb
follow this article please if you find any problem please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap seems to be working for me. You might not be seeing your navbar on the screen because you have a white background and you're using navbar-dark.

```
<body style="background: red">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark big-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    ...
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mov0wjsq/23/

As you can see, the navbar's text is white which is why it wasn't showing up.

Comment: Is there a possibility that it is due to the weak net and that is why the bootstrap link is not opened?

Comment: Use the chrome devtools to see whether the element has any styles being applied to it. If they are, then the link is working and something is wrong with the bootstrap classes you chose.

Comment: Thanks

resolved
I changed dark to light, it worked